# Java dynamic web project is not building

Tags: java, build

I have modified the Web content folder & then did the Clean project followed by build project. But still there is no change in project.
I am using tomcat server 7 & JRE1.7.

What is the best way to build a java dynamic web project? How to ensure each & every file of the project gets re-build?

Comment: What does that mean, "no change in project" ? Do you mean the running application does not change?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot create a comment on this question so have to put it up as an answer..

> Java dynamic web project is not building

What kind of build tool are you using? i.e Maven, Gradle, Ant

---

> I have modified the Web content folder & then did the Clean project
>   followed by build project. But still there is no change in project. I
>   am using tomcat server 7 & JRE1.7.

Tomcat is there to deploy your web project, so if your build is failing you will not be able to deploy it successfully to your tomcat server. Maybe you could provide us with some sort of error message?

---

> What is the best way to build a java dynamic web project? How to
>   ensure each & every file of the project gets re-build?

Don't think you will find any "best way", but there's several options out there you can use. [Fast google search for build tool](http://technologyconversations.com/2014/06/18/build-tools/)

- Maven
- Gradle
- Ant

This is just a few.